# Change checkbox(Activex control) in word 2007

Tags: ms-word, activex, controls

In word 2007, I'm trying to use the default activex control as check box. I would like the color of text changed after some one check the box it.

I know how to get it done with VBA and checkbox formfield, but how can this be done with checkbox(active control)?

Shortly, is there any way I can retrieve the properties or other object information of ActiveX control check box?

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer is too late for the questioner, how ever i am sending it for those who will face this problem later on.

IF you know how to change check box color in VBA then you can do it in word as well. All you have to do is to insert a check box that you can code your self. to do so.

1. Generate Developor's Tab in MS Word by clicking word button at the top left of MS WORD 07 Window; Select Advanced; Select Popular; then in the pan opened, check the check box that contains Developor's tab.
2. Now Click the Developer's Tab, Locate the Control Group and from their, click on legacy tools pull down menu.Click on more controls option at the lowest left of the legacy tools pull down menu. A new Window will open.
3. Scroll down to find the option Micrsoft Forms 2.0checkbox.
4. Click to select it, and you are done. You will receive a check box at the place where your cursor was blinking before you startated this process.
5. This Checkbox is very similar to the Check box from VB. Now if you know the VBA Codes and want to change the properties of check box like color etc. Look at the Control Group in Developer's Tab. Click Design Mode. Now DOUBLE CLICK THE CHECK BOX AND VB CODING FORM OPENS WHERE YOU CAN CODE.
6. In case you do not know how to code in VB, You can still make some useful changes in check box. Single click on the check box and Then Click Properties Immediately below the Design Mode in the devloper's Tab.
7. Here you can make changes in properties.